# Question about an O.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this theorem:

> Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of $\theta$ in a Hilbert space $H$
>   and that $f\in C^2(U,\mathbb{R}^1)$. Assume that $\theta$ is the only
>   critical point of $f$ and that $A=d^2f(\theta)$ ($A$ is a self adjoint operator) with kernel $B$. If
>   $0$ is either an isolated point of the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ or not in
>   $\sigma(A)$, then there exist a ball $B_\delta$, and a $C^1$ mapping
>   $h:B_\delta\cap B\to B^\perp$ such that $$
> > f\circ\phi(z+y)=\frac12(Az,z)+f(h(y)+y),\quad\forall x\in B_\delta, $$
>   where $y=P_Nx$, $z=P_{B^\perp}x$, and $P_B$ is the orthogonal
>   projection onto the subspace $B$.

Let $\eta$ be the flot defined by the following o.d.e

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\eta '(s)=- \frac{A\eta(s)}{||A\eta (s)||}\\
\eta(0)=u
\end{cases}
$$

we have that A is a continuous operator, and that $A_{|_{N}}$ is invertible
if $u \in N$ why $\eta(t,u)\in N$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder, what is $N$?

Comment: $N=B^{\perp}$ such that for a hilbert space $H$, $H=B\oplus B^{\perp}$, $B$ is the ker

Comment: As in $B = \ker A?$

Comment: no we have first $f:U\subset H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $B=\ker f$ and $A=f''(\theta)$, $\theta$ is an isolated critical point of $f$

Comment: Did you mean to say $B = \ker f'$ or something like that?  Because it's not even clear $f$ is linear.

Comment: no $B=\ker f$ and $f$ is not linear $f\in C^2(U,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Then what is the kernel of a nonlinear map?

Comment: ooo ok, so see the first part of theorem:"Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of $\theta$ in a Hilbert space
$H$ and that $f\in C^2(U,\mathbb{R})$. Assume that $\theta$ is the only critical point of $f$
and that $A = df'' (\theta)$ with kernel $B$..."

Comment: @RobertLewis i think that $B=\ker A$

Comment: have you an idea please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12487/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-robert-lewis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the quoted text provided by Vrouvrou, we have that $A = d^2f(\theta)$ for some isolated critical point $\theta$ of $f \in C^2(U, \Bbb R^1)$, and (here we have a "critical" fact) $A$ is self-adjoint, that is, $A = A^T$.

Once it is granted that $A$ is continuous and self-adjoint, the desired result follows immediately; the origins of $A$ as the second derivative of $d^2f(\theta)$ at a critical point $\theta$ may be left behind.

First, we recall the following well-known fact:  with $A$ as above, and $B = \ker A$, we have $A(B^\bot) \subset B^\bot$, since $y \in B^\bot$ if and only if $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$ for any $x \in B$ .  Then for such $x$ and $y$, $\langle x, Ay \rangle = \langle A^Tx, y \rangle = \langle Ax, y \rangle = 0$, since $Ax = 0$, showing $A(B^\bot) \in B^\bot$.  $B$ is also closed since it is the kernel of the continuous operator $A$.

We can use this result to address the problem at hand.  First, note that for $0 \ne \eta \notin B$, $A\eta \ne 0$, for $A\eta = 0$ would imply $\eta \in B = \ker A$, contradicting $\eta \notin B$.  Thus $\Vert A \eta \Vert \ne 0$, so the vector field $-(1 / \Vert A \eta \Vert) A \eta$ is well defined on the open set $H - B$.  If $\eta(s, u)$ satisfies the equation

$\eta'(s, u) = -\dfrac{1}{\Vert A \eta \Vert}A\eta(s, u) \tag{1}$

with

$0 \ne \eta(0, u) = u \in B^\bot, \tag{2}$

then for any constant $x \in B$ we have

$\dfrac{d}{ds}\langle x, \eta(s, u) \rangle = \langle x, \eta'(s, u) \rangle =  \dfrac{-1}{\Vert A \eta \Vert}\langle x, A\eta(s, u) \rangle = \dfrac{-1}{\Vert A \eta \Vert}  \langle Ax, \eta(s, u) \rangle = 0, \tag{3}$

since $Ax$ vanishes by virtue of $x \in B = \ker A$.  This shows that $\langle x, \eta(s, u) \rangle$ is constant along the integral curves $\eta(s, u)$ of (1).  Since $u \in B^\bot$, $\langle x, u \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in B$.  Hence $\langle x, \eta(u, s) \rangle = 0$ as well, showing $\eta(s, u) \in B^\bot$ for all $s$ for which it is defined.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @ Vrouvrou:  my pleasure; it was an  enjoyable experience to work it out!

Comment: please I don't understand this part: "We can use this result to address the problem at hand. First, note that for 0≠η∉B, Aη≠0, for Aη=0 would imply η∈B=kerA, contradicting η∉B" where is the contradiction , contradiction with what please

Comment: I'm at work now; I'll be off in 5 or 6 hours; if you don't hear from me tonight, remind me again.  Regards.

Comment: Dont forget me please

Comment: hi please don't forget me

Comment: @Vrouvrou:  Hi Vrouvrou, sorry it took me so long to get back to you; I got home late from work last night and fell asleep right after dinner.  I just logged in and got your messages, so here we go:  the answer to your question is very simple; indeed, it is almost trivial, following as it does from $B = \ker A$.  The contradiction is between $\eta \in B = \ker A$ and $A\eta \ne 0$; it *would* arise if we assumed some nonzero $\eta \notin B = \ker A$ satisfied $A\eta = 0$, since $A\eta = 0$ by definition implies $\eta \in \ker A = B$.  Once again, sorry about the delay.  Regards.

Comment: so here we just prove that if $A\eta =0$ then $\eta\in B$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou:  right; since $B = \ker A$ by definition, there's really not much to prove!

Comment: @Vrouvrou:  and you are most welcome!

Comment: Thank you, please can you help me here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900836/homology-and-topological-propeties] if you have an idea thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou:  I took a look; it looks complicated.  I'll take another look and see what I can do.  Don't hold your breath, I'm extremely busy right now and will be most of this week.  Regards.