# Homology and topological propeties

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, holonomy

i have this theorem with it's proof but i don't understand the last part [image]

They use this proposition:

[image]

**My question is Why $\varphi^c\cap U_i$ is closed and pairwise disjoint ? where $\varphi^c=\lbrace x, \varphi(x)\leq c\rbrace$**

Please thank you.

Comment: There's a lot of notation in there. What are the $(C)_{c'}$ condition, $K^c_\phi,H_k, M_k,\beta_k$?

Comment: All this have no relation, i juste want to know why $U_i$ is open and $\varphi^c$ is closed implies that $\varphi^c\cap U_i$ is closed ?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is applied (see the middle in $6.6$ ) to $X=\varphi^c\cap C$ and $X_i=\varphi^c\cap U_i$ which is a closed subset in $X$.($X_i=X\cap(\cup_{j\neq i}U_j)^c$ where the c's power is the complementary ).

Comment: I don't understand why $\varphi^c\cap U_i =X\cap(\cup_{i\neq j} U_j)^c$ ? thank you

Comment: If $x\in \varphi^c\cap U_i$, then $x\in X$ and $x\notin U_j$ for $j\neq i$ (because $(U_i)_i$ are pairwise disjoit ).If $x\in X\cap(\cup_{i\neq j}U_j)$ then $x\in X$ and not in any $U_j$ for $j\neq i$, so $x\in U_i$ and that $x\in \varphi^c\cap U_i$.

Comment: I don't understand if $x\in X\cap(\cap_{i\neq j} U_j)^c$ then $x\in X$ but why $x\in \varphi^c$ ?

Comment: $X=\varphi^c\cap C\subset \varphi^c$. and $x\in X\cap(\cup_{j\neq i}U_j)$ there is union not the intersection.

Comment: $\cup_{i\neq j} U_j)^c $ is closed ok, but $\varphi^c$ why is closed ?

Comment: $\varphi^c=\{x/ \varphi(x)\leq c\}=\varphi^{-1}(]-\infty,c])$ l'image réciproque d'un fermé par une application continue est un fermé.

Comment: $X_i=X\cap (\cup_{i\neq j} U_j)^c$ ici $X$ est ouvert et fermé c'est la topologie induite par $X$ c'est ça ? comme $(\cup_{i\neq j} U_j)^c$  est fermé alors $X_i$ l'est aussi c'est ça ?

Comment: Please juste tel me if $\varphi^c\cap U_i=U_i$ please

Comment: Non, j'ai dit que le théorème a été appliquer à $X_i=\varphi^c\cap U_i$ et $X=\varphi^c\cap C=\cup_iX_i$. Je pense que maintenant tu n'a pas besoin d'aide.

Comment: Vous avez répondu a quel question la? c'est la topologie induite ça non ? et est qu'on a $\varphi^c\cap U_i=U_i$ ? et pourquoi svp

Comment: Pourquoi l'égalité $\varphi^c\cap U_i=U_i$? il n'est pas vrai, mais il s'agite de $X$ et des $X_i$ avec la topologie induite .

Comment: Mais j'ai pas compris on a une seule valeurs critique et tout les points critiques sont de niveaux $c$ les voisinages $U_i$ sont assez petit pour que les $x_i$ soit isolé donc tout les élément de $U_i$ sont de niveau $c $

Comment: Moi je parle de votre quesion (pourqui $\varphi^c\cap U_i$ est fermé et où il est fermé), bien sur qu'il a un rapport avec l'application de la proposion6.18,  pour les details tu prend : $X=\varphi^c\cap C$, $A=(\varphi^c\backslash K^c_{\varphi})\cap C$, $X_i=\varphi^c\cap U_i$ et $A_i=\varphi^c\cap U_i\backslash\{x_i\}$.......

Comment: Oui Ok, mais j'ai juste posé une autre question est ce que $\varphi^c\cap U_i=U_i$

Comment: Non, pas forcement.

Comment: Avez vous un exemple s'il vous plait, j'ai le cas $\varphi(x)=x^2$ $c=0$ et $x=0$ point critique et donc l'axe des x inter un voisinage de 0 par exemple ]-1/2,1/2[ est égale a ce voisinage non ?

Comment: Pourqoui vous voulez que cette intersection se réalise ? qu'il est sont intérêt, je pense qu'il n'est pas nécéssaire pour appliquer le théorème d'exision (homologique).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16540/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-hamou).